# azure-graph permission for users.get(principalID)

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

My code (Node.js):

```
const GraphkManagementClient = require('azure-graph');
client = new GraphkManagementClient(credentials, tenantId);
client.users.get(principalID);
```

The last line throws:

> Authorization_RequestDenied: Insufficient privileges to complete the
>   operation.

I know how to grant privileges on Azure portal, but I don't know which one is the correct privilege of azure-graph for performing this operation. The list is so long:

[image]

(And this is just the beginning of the list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you are assigning permissions for the wrong API as per screenshot in your question. It shows "Microsoft Graph" although your code will be using Azure AD Graph API.

In Azure portal navigate to Azure Active Directory > App registrations > Your app > Required permissions > Add (now in the Select an API select "Windows Azure Active Directory")

[image]

Now, if credentials used in your code are client id/app id and app secret, then you need to assign "Read directory data" under Application Permissions. For code like `msRestAzure.loginWithServicePrincipalSecret`

[image]

Otherwise, if you are prompting users to enter their credentials and doing something like interactive login, then assign "Read directory data" under Delegated Permissions. For code like `msRestAzure.interactiveLogin()`

[image]

Once you assign the relevant permissions, if any of those requires Admin consent, like it does in the above two cases I have shown, do the Admin consent. You can do it conveniently for the same tenant using "Grant Permissions" button at the end of the process.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me! Could you also take a look at this question please?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54080176/sending-an-email-using-azure-sdk

Comment: @Alon you're welcome. I'll try to see if I can be of any help with the other question.

Answer (score 0):

Under your Microsoft Graph permissions for the App Registration in Azure Active Directory, grant 'Read Directory Data' permissions. This should be sufficient to make that call work. If that is too elevated, reference this for more information:

[Microsoft Graph Permissions Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/graph/permissions-reference#user-permissions)