# Sending an email using Azure SDK

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I use azure-graph in my Node.js project:

```
const MsRest = require('ms-rest-azure');    
const credentials = await MsRest.loginWithServicePrincipalSecret(keys.appId, keys.pass, keys.tenantId, { tokenAudience: 'graph' });
const GraphkManagementClient = require('azure-graph');
const client = new GraphkManagementClient(credentials, subscriptionId);
return client.users.get(principalID);
```

I want to use the Azure SDK also to send emails.

I know how to do that in low level using the API directly:

[image]

But I want to do it via the SDK like the rest of my project.

My problem is, I have not found any method for sending an email in the docs: [azure-graph package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-graph/index?view=azure-node-latest). I need a method that allows me (with the proper privileges of course) to send email as any user in the organization.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Graph JavaScript SDK which is a wrapper around the Microsoft Graph API that can be used server-side and in the browser to send mails to users.  Please refer to [Graph Javascript SDK](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript) to learn more about the same.  Also, refer to [nodejs-connect-sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/nodejs-connect-sample) to use Microsoft Graph API and the Graph JavaScript SDK to send an email.

Comment: I am using Node.js, not cliet side. I know how to call the API I mentioned from Node.js. I want to use Azure SDK.